# How can I prevent Backblaze from frequently (every few days) reuploading my entire external hard drives?

Tags: windows, backup, external-hard-drive, backblaze

It seems that Backblaze is frequently (every few days) reuploading my entire external hard drives. Backblaze already has the files on its server, so it's only scanning my entire external hard drives, get some checksum of each file, compare against the files on its server and then skipping the files. But that still means reading and computing the checksum of many TBs of files every few days, which I don't want. I still want Backblaze to upload new or changes files.

How can I prevent Backblaze from frequently (every few days) reuploading my entire external hard drives? I use Backblaze on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: You transition to Backblaze B2, Blackblaze Personal, as described is a [continuous daily backup](https://www.reddit.com/r/backblaze/comments/njkxdh/bzservexe_can_i_how_to_disable_it_at_startup/). Backblaze support might have other options.

Comment: What makes you think it's *"reuploading my entire external hard drives"* ? I'm not sure how it could be expected to know which files have changed without looking at the files… to see if they've changed. It's unlikely to be scanning though the files like an antivirus, just checking last modified dates. I'm sure you'd notice if it was uploading terabytes of data - it would take weeks if not months. I have mine set to only run overnight, but I just switched it over & it sent a whole 650MB in seconds.

Comment: @Tetsujin Backblaze already has the files on its server, so it's only scanning my entire external hard drives, get some checksum of each file, compare against the files on its server and then skipping the files. I can see that it is scanning the entire drives because I see a few TBs in the remaining files transfer progress

Comment: I'd ask Backblaze how their system works, whether your perception is correct & what you may be able to do about it. It's a proprietary structure; little anyone outside the company can say about it, other than what we have here - speculation.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks yes I've done so on https://redd.it/18aiidr I was hoping that maybe some super users on super user SE had some idea based on their experience (e.g., "clicking on backup now will trigger an entire rescan:)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - As my link suggests, from the developer who wrote the service, it’s a daily backup. That requires determining which files changed….daily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blackblaze only uploads the checksums of the files, not the files
themselves, for the entire partition.
The checksums are calculated locally by the application.

If this is still too much, you may restrict further the Blackblaze
backup operation by running its application (usually resident in
the traybar) and entering Settings.

In the Schedule tab, you can set the schedule to
Continuously, Once Per Day or Only when I click BackupNOW.
The last option will stop all backups until you decide to permit
them again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one event that triggers re-queue of all data on a drive, [explained](https://redd.it/k3dev9) by Backblaze employee [clunkclunk](https://www.reddit.com/user/clunkclunk):

> Since the drive was deselected then reselected for backup, Backblaze has re-queued all the data on that drive. As each file comes up in the queue, it's checksummed to see if it's already been backed up, and if it has, it's just noted in the logs and not backed up again. We call that process "de-duplication."